# How to convert a requests GET request in Python to asyncio with payloads?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, wikidata-api

I am trying to parallelize requests to the Wikidata API using Python's asyncio module.

My current synchronous script does the following:

```
import requests

base_url = "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php&"
payload = {
        "action": "query",
        "list": "search",
        "srsearch": search_term,
        "language": "en",
        "format": "json",
        "origin": "*",
    }
res = requests.get(base_url, params=payload)
```

I am trying to do the same using `asyncio`, to send requests asynchronously.

From [this blogpost](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html) and the documentation, I understood that I need something like:

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            response = await response.read()
```

However, I did not manage to find how to add these payloads in the request. Do I have to reconstruct the URL manually or is there a way to send the payloads in asyncio?

Comment: What is `ClientSession`?  Please make your code complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```py
async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, params=payload) as response:
            response = await response.read()
```